# Does it break anything if I alias “..” to be “cd ..”?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, alias

I find myself wanting to type `..` instead of `cd ..` a lot, so I created an alias for it in one my of my shells. It works as expected, and it doesn't seem to break basic `cd` and `ls` usage.

Is doing this a bad idea?

Comment: Is it a bad idea? Only in the sense that you're looking for a shortcut to counter carelessness instead of developing better habits.

Comment: Good point. At first I thought that something so simple wouldn't ruin me, but it probably will. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't break anything, but aliasing something as basic as `cd ..` might lead to bad habits. Really, you're better off training your fingers to do the right thing.

Also, what happens when you move to a new system, or get a new job, or need to maintain 1000 systems. You'll need to alias `..` again, which can be a pain.

Many of us have done that in the past with other aliases, and learned that this was a bad idea, sometimes through a harsh experience.

Comment: Which is why I tend to not use aliases in general. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: I use aliases for long or hard to remember commands, but I create new names for the aliases so that they don't interfere with existing aliases.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing uses `..` as a command, so this is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

> Is doing this a bad idea?

**Yes**

Comment: When you go on other systems, you'll instinctively type '..' instead of 'cd ..' because of the bad habit.